# Усовершенствование скрипта

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, responsive

Написал горизонтальное резиновое меню для себя. В принципе что хотел реализовать то и вышло(выпадающее меню на несколько колонок, при уменьшении все плавно смещает и обрезает текст в нужный момент), возможно у Вас будут другие взгляды на определенные вещи, буду рад услышать. Но вся суть вопроса немного в другом.

После нескольких ресайзов `hover` заметно стает замедление срабатывать. Мои знания jQuery пока что не дают ответа на вопрос почему так может быть. Может кто-то подскажет в чем суть проблемы и как ее можно решить. 
Демо [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/marchyshyn/pen/vNyWGg)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что ты только добавляешь обработчики событий, не удаляя предыдущие. Соответственно, через какое то время своевременная обработка большого числа однотипных событий  начинает вызывать у браузера затруднения.

Решить данную проблему можно используя [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) и [jQuery.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) которые позволяют добавлять и удалять события.